# Karma + JSPM + Typescript - not found '.ts.js'

Tags: javascript, typescript, karma-runner, jspm, karma-coverage

Mainly just trying to get Karma+JSPM to play nice on loading the .ts files but having absolutely no luck.

I see up a [discussion repo](https://github.com/Larchy/karma-jspm-typescript-coverage/tree/master) with a stripped down example.

Basically JSPM within Karma is seemingly ignoring the `defaultJSExtensions: true` and package level `"defaultExtension": "ts"` configurations when running in Karma giving the following error when attempting to load files:

```
$ npm test

> karma-jspm-typescript-coverage@1.0.0 test C:\examples\karma-jspm-typescript-coverage
> karma start

18 08 2016 17:29:31.937:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.2.0 server started at http://localhost:1337/
18 08 2016 17:29:31.943:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
18 08 2016 17:29:31.974:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
18 08 2016 17:29:33.075:INFO [Chrome 52.0.2743 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#jTR10wm0CWNIfrdhAAAA with id 75197348
18 08 2016 17:29:33.317:WARN [web-server]: 404: /src/app/app.spec.ts.js
Chrome 52.0.2743 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:1337/src/app/app.spec.ts.js
        Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:1337/src/app/app.spec.ts.js
        Error loading http://localhost:1337/src/app/app.spec.ts.js

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Note the **.ts.js** extension. Tried everyting from [karma-typescript-proprocessor](https://github.com/sergeyt/karma-typescript-preprocessor) to loading via a different JSPM config than what would be ran with live.

Trying to keep it so there's no need to manage the `.js` compiled files and only work with the `.ts` files. The development server and bundling/build are fully functional - this testing and coverage piece is my last hurdle.

Please let me know if there any kind of direction you can give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

package level `"defaultExtension": "ts"` does not apply because karma is running in the top-level directory, one level above `src` directory which contains config.js with

```
baseURL: '.'
```

If I duplicate `app` package config there with `src` prepended to it, like this:

```
  packages: {
    "src/app": {
      "main": "app",
      "defaultExtension": "ts",
      "meta": {
        "*.ts": {
          "loader": "ts"
        }
      }
    },
    "app": {
      "main": "app",
      "defaultExtension": "ts",
      "meta": {
        "*.ts": {
          "loader": "ts"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

I'm able to get one step further. I'm now getting

`Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/jspm_packages/github/frankwallis/plugin-typescript@5.0.9.js`

which indicates to me that karma-jspm plugin is unable to serve source files at URLs where SystemJS expects them to be

Comment: You are a genius! Added that and a proxy to the karma configuration.
`proxies : {
   "/src"           : "/base/src",
   "/jspm_packages" : "/base/src/jspm_packages"
  },`

Changes have been updated in the [github](https://github.com/Larchy/karma-jspm-typescript-coverage) project.